# Which HTML5 Tags Should Only Occur Once in a Document?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

This is mainly a question about semantic markup. I believe there are some tags which ought to only occur once in an HTML5 document for that document to be considered semantically correct. I believe `<nav>` is one such tag. I wonder if `<h1>` also falls into this category. Are there any others? So far this is the list, maybe someone could flush out the list?

- `<nav>`
- `<h1>`

Comment: Neither `nav` or `h1` are semantically bound to being unique.  Having `h1` elements inside each `section` element of an `article` is arguably semantically valid for example.  You can also place various secondary and tertiary navigation structures within `nav` elements in addition to your main navigation and remain both semantically and syntactically valid.

Comment: A W3C grammar for HTML5 and a parser would verify this very quickly.

Comment: Having multiple h1 is not a syntax error but it is recommended to have just one h1 in a page for SEO.

Comment: @duffymo could you provide any links to such a grammar-checker/parser? afaik the regular w3 validator doesn't provide this. or does it?

Comment: @VahidND Actually HTML5 introduces new rules which mean you can begin any distinct section with any heading element you like and the browser is required to adjust the actual outline level to fit within the hierarchy of the page. So you can begin each section with h1 to give yourself more sub-header levels to play with, and it's perfectly allowed.

Comment: @Arkanon - Sadly, no. Browsers are known not to implement the HTML5 outline algorithm. Neither do screen readers (except for a broken implementation in one version of JAWS) and there's no evidence that search engines exploit it either. For that reason, best practice advice in the latest HTML5.1 spec is to use H1-H6 the same way as you would in HTML4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only tags that *need* to be unique on the page are:

- `<html>`
- `<head>`

  - `<title>`
- `<body>`

  - `<main>`

The rest can occur as many times as you want, and it'll still be completely valid, even semantically.